# Passing and updating an environment variable constantly

Tags: linux, variables, environment, updating

I need a way to constantly update a environment variable from a script. I need to use that environment variable in another program almost real time.

What I have is this code:

```
# !bin/bash
while :

do

AMA="$(cut -c 1-13 text.txt)"

source directory/this_script

done
```

I am getting the right information from my file when running cut this way. I just need to get this variable permanently updating if possible. Also a way to even get it to the environment.

Slackware Linux

Comment: It seems like you may be trying to implement the wrong solution to your overall problem. You have a shell script that runs the same routine repeatedly and uses a value from an environment variable. And you want to be able to update that environment variable as you go. What's the real problem? Also, are you really running a bash script that infinitely and  recursively sources itself?

Comment: What I want to do is get the number from the text file that I have and insert into an enviroment variable so I can use it it another already prebuilt program.

Comment: Apologies if what I do have sucks... =/

Comment: No apologies necessary. I wasn't saying anything about you. (1) Do you always re-run the program? or (2) Is the program running constantly and you want to change its environment while its running (which is not possible btw)?

Comment: I have another program that can read environment variables. Prebuilt before me. I want use that feature by updating a custom made environment variable and have that program thats pre built read it. The pre built program I can have run over and over and so it ill read as my environment variable is updated.

Comment: My only issue is actually creating an environment variable thats "permanent" that can have its value updated. The numbers I am reading are sent from a program I made that sends a file with a number in it to another computer

Comment: Environments are copied. So, program A can set an environment and run program B. B gets a *copy* of A's environment. A cannot see or modify B's environment once B is run, and B has no way of seeing A's environment once run (well, normally). It would be better to find another way to communicate between A and a constantly running B. Now, if every time you want to send a file, you run a new B, then it would get a fresh environment.

Comment: I missed your other comment. Using A and B again where B is the prebuilt program that you run over and over and which uses an environment variable: in a shell script like you have above: `export VAR=value` then run B, or you can shorthand it with `VAR=value B`. Those are not quite the same, but they have the same effect on B.